# Gave qurban to parent

Tags: sadaqah, parents, eid-ul-adha

I didn't do qurban (قربان) yet, but yes I do sadaqah. In fact of Sunnah that any Muslim around mosque, no matter he is rich or poor, anyone got qurban include my family. But in personal reason that we think we are living enough food and money, living a better life than my parent when they didn't get any qurban, I decided to give them all qurban meat that I have.

**Is it allow by Islam?**

Comment: Please clarify one thing, you said you didn't did qurban, and you gave all qurban meat to your parents... how you gave qurban meat to your parents when you didn' did qurban. Was it meat which came from other muslims who did qurban?

Comment: -1 For not asking a question!

Answer (score 1):

```
                                    In the name of Allah
```

In regards to your question

> Gave qurban to parent

I found a hadith from Imam Baqir (امام الباقر) (a.s.) that said:

> Commonly, Imam Ali (علیه السلام) didn't use to eat at ًQurban Day in order
>   to eat from his Qurbani's meat. / من لا یحضره الفقیه - ترجمه، ج‌2، ص:
>   214‌

And also Imam Ali (a.s.) said:

> Eat nothing except your Qurbani’s meat, it would be no problem (not
>   necessary) to do Qurbani if you have not financial ability.  من لا
>   یحضره الفقیه - ترجمه، ج‌2 ص213‌

---

In regard to the division of Qurbani, it is said in the narrations that

> Shia Imams used to give 1/3 of the Qurbani to the neighbors, 1/3
>   to the poor people who were requesting, and were keeping the last 1/3
>   for their families.  من لا یحضره الفقیه - ترجمه، ج‌2، ص: 381‌

Therefore it is considered as a Mustahab practice (not Wajib) to divide the Qurbani into 3 parts, as a result it wouldn’t be prohibited in order to keep all the meat of Qurbani for ourselves. (Or apparently as what you stated).

---

**Reference:**

- من لا یحضره الفقیه
- [www.tebyan.net](http://www.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=185915)

Answer (score 0):

Gave sacrifices to parents?
Abu Jafar, peace be upon him, said that the Commander of the Faithful, peace be upon him, would not eat anything on the Day of Adha until he had eaten from it.
Imam Baqir (AS) said: The method of the Commander of the Faithful (AS) was such that on the day of Eid al-Adha, he did not eat food to eat food from his sacrificial meat.
And also that Imam said:“And do not eat anything on the Day of Adha except from your sacrifice and your sacrifice, if you are strong enough for it.”
On the day of Eid al-Adha, do not eat anything except the meat of your sacrifice, and if you do not have the financial means to sacrifice, then you are excused.
According to these narrations, if it was possible for a person to sacrifice on the day of Eid, the first thing he ate on that day was the meat of the same victim.
“Ali ibn al-Husayn and Abu Jafar (peace be upon him) used to give one-third as alms to their neighbours, and one-third to all of them.”
And Ali ibn al-Husayn and Abu Ja'far (peace be upon them) used to make one third of the sacrifice as alms of their neighbors and the other third as alms of the seekers, and they kept the third third for the family.
Therefore, if someone wanted to keep all the meat of the victim, he would not be forbidden.

Ref: https://www.talab.org/religion/religious-orders/%D8%A7%D8%AD%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%85-%DA%AF%D9%88%D8%B4%D8%AA-%D9%82%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86%DB%8C.html